# Macports cccc terminates when run - how to solve

Tags: macports

One tool I really appreciate when analyzing source code for software is Sourcemonitor, but unfortunately it is only available on windows.  Having searched around for alternatives on my mac, it seems that cccc is a tool that fits the bill.

I installed it via macports but it terminates when I run it.  This is the error I get:

```
Parsing
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

Does anyone know of a way to fix this error?

Comment: how do you use Macports? Have you installed MacPorts and then upgraded your OS? The best way in such cases are reinstall MacPorts at all or at least rebuild by using `sudo port upgrade -f installed`

Comment: @EirNym I tried the steps that you mentioned but I still get the error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If clean installation of mac ports gives you this error, you have to report it. But on my local installation I able to build cccc without special variants

Comment: @EirNym I can build cccc no problem, it is just when I execute it I get this error.  Can you confirm it works when analysing a source file?  I will uninstall/re-install mac ports tonight and try again.

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I don't know your story, there's possible issues which can be found over Google:

1. You've installed MacPorts then upgraded your OS
2. You've installed MacPorts then upgraded XCode where produced ABI by compiler has been changed (such as migration from gcc to clang)
3. You've built some libraries from ports with one compiler, other part with different one (e.g. some library has been built with clang and later you've switched to gcc).

In these cases the best you can do is reinstalling your MacPorts from scratch without mixing compilers.

Comment: Thanks Eir Nym, indeed my xcode was out of date.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does 'reinstalling your MacPorts from scratch' mean reinstall MacPorts itself + every single port? Or only the specific ports involved?

Comment: I do reinstall all installed ports. Something like this: `port selfupdate && port fetch installed && port upgrade --force installed`